# ERROR:gcm_channel_status_request.cc(145)] GCM channel request failed message shows in terminal with python project

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

when I try to use python + Selenium to run my code, the error message shows in the terminal during the program is running, it has no effect of my program, but sort of annoying, does anyone have any solution to tell me why the error shows, and how to disable the error message.
my network is located in China, and our network policy disables the access to Google, is the may the cause?

```
[21792:15920:1230/144009.402:ERROR:gcm_channel_status_request.cc(145)] GCM channel request failed.
```

anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am in Australia, and I get this message when my python application is sleeping. Your question is the first page Google suggested  I'll post anything I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is not a definitive answer; it is very rough conclusions drawn from a quick investigation.

[GCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging) is Google Cloud Messaging. It appears that the Selenium Chrome extension is using GCN. See for example https://pushwizard.com/chrome-gcm-messaging.

I see these messages when my Python Selenium Chrome application is sleeping and I hibernate the machine. It may occur at other times.

I surmise that the Selenium Python backend is using GCN and uses a ping or keep-alive type of message to find out if the Chrome browser is still there. I further surmise that since my Python application takes much less memory than the Chrome browser, my app wakes up first, pings the browser, and reports that there was no response.

Since it's not causing a problem this is enough for me.

Comment: Hi THANKS, but that is kind of annoying for application since my case need to continue input something then got output, let's waiting for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Messaging is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) - you should use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) instead.

You may need to update your selenium webdriver for chrome.

Since your access to google ( and I think google services too ) is disabled this also could be the issue. To test this, you should go and implement the selenium application with firefox (or any other non chromium based browser) ; which shouldn't use google services inherently. ( but i am not 100% sure about that )